# Build error when using external toolchain in Buildroot

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

I am trying to use externel toolchain option in Buildroot and to use `gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz` as external toolchain. I am following the steps mentioned in [Buildroot manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_cross_compilation_toolchain) section 6.1.3. I already have the toolchain tarball so I did not do `make sdk` part. In the `menuconfig` I have specified like below:

1. Set Toolchain type to External toolchain
2. Set Toolchain to Custom toolchain
3. Set Toolchain origin to Toolchain to be downloaded and installed
4. Set Toolchain URL to file:///path/to/your/sdk/tarball.tar.gz : In my case I have set it to file:////root/br-tcg4/tmp/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz

Then when I do `make` I get below errors:

```
.
.
.
Unpacking toolchain to "/root/br-tcg4/bat/buildscripts/../../tmp/toolchain" ...
done

Current STW RootFs version: "STW-V4.00r1"
Have you updated the version? Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Make rfs ...
make: Entering directory '/root/br-tcg4/libs/br_pjt'
Makefile:1051: warning: overriding recipe for target '/root/br-tcg4/libs/br_pjt/output/staging'
Makefile:475: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/root/br-tcg4/libs/br_pjt/output/staging'
/usr/bin/make -j1 O=/root/br-tcg4/libs/br_pjt/output HOSTCC="/usr/bin/gcc" HOSTCXX="/usr/bin/g++" syncconfig
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/br-tcg4/libs/br_pjt'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/br-tcg4/libs/br_pjt'
tar-1.29.cpio.gz: OK (sha256: 9173f222464dd3676118408840da5990527062b5c7daf6487bed7c396c45bfb1)
>>> toolchain-external-custom  Downloading
cp: cannot stat '/root/br-tcg4/tmp/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz': No such file or directory
--2022-02-01 20:02:13--  http://sources.buildroot.net/toolchain-external-custom/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz
Resolving sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)... 172.67.72.56, 104.26.1.37, 104.26.0.37, ...
Connecting to sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)|172.67.72.56|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-02-01 20:02:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2022-02-01 20:02:14--  http://sources.buildroot.net/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz
Resolving sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)... 172.67.72.56, 104.26.1.37, 104.26.0.37, ...
Connecting to sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)|172.67.72.56|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2022-02-01 20:02:14 ERROR 404: Not Found.

make: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:171: /root/br-tcg4/libs/br_pjt/output/build/toolchain-external-custom/.stamp_downloaded] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/root/br-tcg4/libs/br_pjt'

------------- Error occured! -------------
```

When I checked `http://sources.buildroot.net/toolchain-external-custom` there is no file `gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz`.

Can anyone please let me know how to properly use external toolchain option in Buildroot?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

P.S: I am using Buildroot 2020.02.12 and Ubuntu 20.04 as build system. please let me know if any info is missing here.

Comment: Why are you using subdirectories under **/root/**? Are you (unnecessarily) running Buildroot with elevated privileges?

Comment: Hello @sawdust, there are no explicit reasons to run Buildroot with elevated privileges. I will change the location going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that you have already downloaded the custom toolchain tarball, why not simply manually install (i.e. un-archive) the custom toolchain, and then choose the appropriate Buildroot options (i.e. for a `Pre-installed toolchain`)?

For instance I install toolchains at **/opt/**, and Linaro toolchains under **/opt/linaro/**. The same toolchain that you're using is installed on my development PC as:

```
$ ls -go /opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 6  4096 Dec  4  2019 arm-linux-gnueabihf
drwxr-xr-x 2  4096 Dec  4  2019 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 11337 Dec  4  2019 gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-linux-manifest.txt
drwxr-xr-x 3  4096 Dec  4  2019 include
drwxr-xr-x 3  4096 Dec  4  2019 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3  4096 Dec  4  2019 libexec
drwxr-xr-x 8  4096 Dec  4  2019 share
$
```

Buildroot will simply use symbolic links to the pre-installed executables for storage efficiency.  Thus when you have several Buildroot project directories that use the same external toolchain, there is only a single copy of each pre-installed toolchain executable.  Whereas if you (download &) install the external toolchain, each Buildroot project directory will have its own copy of the executables.

> Can anyone please let me know how to properly use external toolchain option in Buildroot?

The following Buildroot menuconfig is setup for a pre-installed Linaro toolchain at  **/opt/linaro/...** that works reliably for me:

```
    Toolchain type (External toolchain)  --->
    *** Toolchain External Options ***
    Toolchain (Custom toolchain)  --->
    Toolchain origin (Pre-installed toolchain)  --->
(/opt/linaro/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/) Toolchain path 
(arm-linux-gnueabihf) Toolchain prefix
    External toolchain gcc version (7.x)  --->
    External toolchain kernel headers series (4.10.x)  --->
    External toolchain C library (glibc/eglibc)  --->
[*] Toolchain has SSP support?
[*]   Toolchain has SSP strong support?
[*] Toolchain has RPC support?
[*] Toolchain has C++ support?
[ ] Toolchain has D support?
[ ] Toolchain has Fortran support?
[ ] Toolchain has OpenMP support?
[ ] Copy gdb server to the Target
    *** Host GDB Options ***
...
```

Comment: Super, it worked like a charm. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: Now, I want to do some cross-compilation of applications using same cross-compiler toolchain. I have previously done it using Yocto. But I am bit confused doing same in buildroot. In Yocto we need to source environment script prior to doing `cmake`. But in buildroot I don't see any such script which will set needed environment variables. I read that in newer versions of buildroot we can use  `BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_ENVIRONMENT_SETUP` to obtain environment-setup script generated. I have set the cross-compiler toolchain path in PATH var and did `export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-`.

Comment: [cont] Is this enough in Buildroot? Now can I do out-of-source build using `cmake`? I believe `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and `CMAKE_SYSROOT` should be set to `/opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/`. Can you please let me know if this the correct way to do it?

Comment: I know nothing about cmake.  You need to clarify: are you asking about (a) building an application program within Buildroot as a *package*, or (b) simply using the "external" toolchain in any subdirectory?